# Converting getting JSON objects from string pulled from URL

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to get JSON data from a string that I have created from data I have pulled down from a URL. So far this is what I have in my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        String url = "http://www.example.com/api/core/v1/my/";
        String unp = username+":"+password;


        class MyUser {
              public String firstName;
              public String lastName;
        }


        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet header = new HttpGet(url);
            String encoded_login = Base64.encodeToString(unp.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            header.setHeader(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded_login));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(header);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;line.replaceAll("throw 'allowIllegalResourceCall is false.';", "")) {
                Vector<Object> vector = new Vector<Object>();
                vector.add(line);
                String result = vector.toString();


                JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(result);
                System.out.println("name=" + json.get("name"));
                System.out.println("width=" + json.get("width"));

                System.out.println(line);
            }       


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(MY_APP_TAG, "Error e: " + e);
        }

        }
```

This is pulling the correct json data down, but every time i try to parse the data i am getting the following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(923): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(923): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at basic.authentication.BasicAuthenticationActivity.onCreate(BasicAuthenticationActivity.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/AndroidRuntime(923): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am new to JSON so figuring this out is proving a real big challenge so any help with this is much appreciated.

Also, the JSON data come through like this:

```
{
  "enabled" : true,
  "email" : "example@gmail.com",
  "firstName" : "example firstname",
  "lastName" : "example lastname",
  "name" : "example fullname",
  "level" : {
```

I know that these are JSON objects and not JSON arrays.

Comment: Your primary error is: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` - i.e. it's not finding your JSON library. Did you download another JSON implementation but haven't put the .jar in a folder named `libs` in your project?

Comment: I have checked this and everything is correct as i can see, i am just really confused with this right now. JSON is driving me insane

Comment: Start by removing that 3rd party library you are using. Android has a (basic) JSON parser already (in the org.json package). Secondly, your HTTP code is whack - you need to move the HTTP download into an `AsyncTask` - and your method of turning the response into a String is at best dysfunctional - you **should** start by using the `org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils#toString(HttpEntity)` method (also included in the SDK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create a JSon object using your string, like this:

```
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
```

Now, get the desired value like this:

```
     String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` because the JVM can't find `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` at runtime.  Check that the library is included in the proper directory and is added in your classpath.

Comment: I have included this import and its still the same, do you think that there is something in the code that i am doing wrong?